# Content Grouping Not Showing in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on a Google Analytics project and am trying to implement Content Grouping.

I enter the 'Admin' panel, and look under 'View' between 'Goals' and 'Filters' but 'Content Grouping' is not there.

I should have access to this with even the lowest permissions granted from my client, correct?  Is there somewhere else I can find the Content Grouping settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create Content Groups, you need to have [Edit](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en) permission for that view.